# Display values from two hash's in a single html table

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, hash, view, html-table

I'm trying to create a table in one of my views that displays a combination of values from two separate hash's in a single row. The desired output would have three columns: Material, Units and Net Weight.

In my controller I generate the hashes like so:

```
@materialGroups = @shipment.shipmentDetails.count(:group => :product_name)
@materialTotals = @shipment.shipmentDetails.group(:product_name).sum(:net_weight)
```

@materialGroups contains the product_name and a count of number of units for each product
@materialTotals contains the product_name and a sum of the net_weights for each product.

My view contains the following code to display the table:

```
<table class="table">
        <th>Material</th>
        <th>Units</th>
        <th>Net Weight</th> 

        <% @materialGroups.each do | product_name, count| %>
        <% @materialTotals.each do | ship_net_weight, sum | %>
        <tr>
        <td><%= product_name %></td>
        <td nowrap="true"><%= number_with_delimiter(count) %></td>  
        <td nowrap="true"><%= number_with_delimiter(sum) %> lbs</td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
        <% end %>
</table>
```

This all works fine as long as only one product_name group is returned (ie. Only Steel was in ShipmentDetails). However if I have more than one product_name (ie. Steel and Copper) in ShipmentDetails for a Shipment, I get duplicate rows in the table for each product_name. So instead of having one row for Steel with 20 Units @ a net weight of 200 lbs, I get two identical rows. And two identical rows for Copper.

How can either:

1. Iterate over the two hash's correctly in the view?
2. Or alternately, generate just one hash and iterate over it for the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `select` you can produce one hash to loop over.  Try:

```
@materials = @shipment.shipmentDetails.select("count(*), sum(net_weight), product_name").group(:product_name)
```

Then in your view you can do something like:

```
<% @materials.each do |m| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= m.product_name %></td>
    <td nowrap="true"><%= number_with_delimiter(m.count) %></td>  
    <td nowrap="true"><%= number_with_delimiter(m.sum) %> lbs</td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks! worked great, only note is that I had to add an as clause to count(*) and sum(net_weight) in order to access the values.